# How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, triggers

I'm writing a macro that creates tickets on a database based on alerts received from a Nagios server as an email. However, I cannot let the macro run in an infinite loop while checking for mails because it is just too resource heavy and makes my desktop hang. I need to find a way to trigger the macro only when a new mail is received.

I looked for something along the lines of NewMail events on the MSDN website, but I can't find anything coherent. Can anyone show me just a bit of sample code to show how to trigger macros from new mail events?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This code will add an event listener to the default local Inbox, then take some action on incoming emails. You need to add that action in the code below.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

  On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item 
    ' ******************
    ' do something here
    ' ******************
  End If
ProgramExit: 
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
  Resume ProgramExit 
End Sub
```

After pasting the code in `ThisOutlookSession` module, you must restart Outlook.

Comment: My bad, had macros disabled. Bit silly that there isn't different level of macro security for this scenario though.

Comment: @JimmyPena Where is Items_ItemAdd called?

Comment: Worked with Outlook 2016

Comment: Works for the first couple of emails during the first couple of minutes, and then suddenly stops being triggered. Any idea why?

Comment: Nothing Is happening for Me

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this inside `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Call Your_main_macro
End Sub
```

My outlook vba just fired when I received an email and had that application event open.

Edit: I just tested a hello world msg box and it ran after being called in the `application_newmail` event when an email was received.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't seem to be working. I tried running the macro and then sending myself a mail, but I couldn't get my macro to run until I reinitialized the whole thing. What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: Where did you have the code in my answer? I placed it in `ThisOutlookSession` and left it. No need to run the macro it will trigger when a mail is received.

Comment: I had it pasted in ThisOutlookSession too, but it's giving me a lot of problems during running. I can't even point to the root of the problem, my sub just does utterly random things...

Comment: If you paste something like this in the 'do something here' section: `Call Your_main_macro`, I have found that the macro has to be stored in the same module, `ThisOutlookSession`. If it was in a different module, I got an error. I had to restart Outlook for any changes to take effect.