# Turn on envelope icon for new mail for specific mailbox account only

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two mailbox accounts in Outlook 2010.

- Primary: Bob@something.com
- Secondary: help@something.com

Every time I receive new mail to help@something.com I get the envelope of new mail.

I want to receive the envelope only for Bob@something.com

I cancelled the option to receive envelopes in Outlook.

I created a rule in Outlook 2010 under the account of Bob@something.com

I have the option to run a script but its empty.

I need to write VBA code that can do it:

```
If (mail was send to Bob@something.com) Then
    show Envelope
End If
```

I know that I can just add the folder of help@something.com instead of its account but it is not possible in my environment (cloud users).

I searched on the web and didn't find anything like this. For example, I did not find what code line can turn the envelope on in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you find displaying a message box is an acceptable alternative then the Run a Script format is described here [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)

From the rule you pass the new mail as "Item" like this:

```
Public Sub DisplayMessageBox(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    ' You need not do anything with "Item" just use it as a trigger
    MsgBox "New mail in Bob@something.com"

    ' or you can enhance the message using "Item" properties
    MsgBox "New mail in Bob@something.com - Subject: " & Item.Subject

End Sub
```

You may also consider ItemAdd or NewMailEx which are a little more complex.

There is an ItemAdd example here [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)