# Macro in outlook to mark emails as read

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I want to use a macro in outlook 2013. This macro is supposed to mark any emails arriving a specific folder ('work' folder) as read. I'm not familiar with vb. Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure, I have heard this one before of wanting emails automatically read. You have two options:

a) Use Ctrl-A (select all mail in folder), Ctrl-Q (mark selection as read)

b) Use New Email Event something like:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    vID = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Dim i as Long, objMail as Outlook.MailItem
    For i = 0 To UBound(vID)
        Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(vID(i))
        objMail.Unread = False
    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    ' version to select folder
    Dim i As Long, objMail As Outlook.MailItem, mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("YOURACCOUNT").Folders("[Gmail]").Folders("Sent Mail")
    For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count
        If mpfInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
            Set objMail = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i)
            objMail.UnRead = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I use the macro for a specific folder and not every email item?

Comment: Looks like the revised code processes mpfInbox for every mail received. ItemAdd for 'work' folder would be appropriate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a rule which can trigger your macro.

I'd not suggest working with the NewMailEx event because it is not fired in some case and may introduce issues. See [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/) for more information.