# Executing script on receipt of new email in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to create some sort of trigger in an outlook where a python script will be executed as new emails are received in inbox. I did refer to this link: [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook) and have written the following script:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 default local Inbox
 Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
Private Sub test_macro(ByVal item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
  Set Msg = item
  Ret_Val = Shell("python <path-of-python-script>")
  Debug.Print "Value: ", Ret_Val
  If Ret_Val <> 0 Then
     MsgBox "Couldn't run python script", vbOKOnly
  End If
End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Although its not giving any error but due to some reasons my python script is not executing. I've configured macro settings in outlook accordingly and also created a new rule according to documentation available. But still not able to achieve the intended result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your `test_macro` sub to `Items_ItemAdd`. There is a reason why that name is used in the answer that you copied your code from. `Items_ItemAdd` means that the sub is an event handler for `ItemAdd` event of object called `Items`.

**Couple of notes:**

- Make sure to put your code into the `ThisOutlookSession` module and restart Outlook to initialize it. The code won't work in a standard module.
- There is no need to set any rules to run this macro. It will run whenever a new item is received (or added to inbox).
- I would suggest not to reuse class names for class instances (objects), as you do eg. in `Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items`. It is confusing.
- To test this, just copy a an e-mail from some folder (Ctrl+C) and paste it into your Inbox (Ctrl+V). The macro should run.

Try the following code exactly as I pasted it. (I kept your confusing variable names.)

***ThisOutlookSession:***

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' default local Inbox
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    MsgBox "Items_ItemAdd listener initialized."
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = Item
        MsgBox "Python script will run now."
        Ret_Val = Shell("python <path-of-python-script>")
        Debug.Print "Value: ", Ret_Val
        If Ret_Val <> 0 Then
           MsgBox "Couldn't run python script", vbOKOnly
        End If
    End If

ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```