# VBA: Only save the last (The most recent) email attachment in a local folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to save the attachment of last email that has a specific subject (the most recent one) to a local folder, to do this I have created a folder in my Outlook and a rule to send every email with that specific subject to this folder. I have found a code that does what I needed except that it saves every single attachment in the email folder rather than saving only the most recent one. This is the code: how could i modify it so that it does what i need?

```
   Sub Test()
   'Arg 1 = Folder name of folder inside your Inbox
   'Arg 2 = File extension, "" is every file
   'Arg 3 = Save folder, "C:\Users\Ron\test" or ""
   '        If you use "" it will create a date/time stamped folder for you in your "Documents" folder
'        Note: If you use this "C:\Users\Ron\test" the folder must exist.

    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "Dependencia Financiera", "xls", "W:\dependencia financiera\test dependencia\"

End Sub



Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    i = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
   ' If DestFolder = "" Then
       ' Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       ' Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       ' MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
       ' DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
       ' If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            'fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
       ' End If
    'End If

    'If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        'DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    'End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    'JUST BEED TGE FIRST EMAIL
    'Debug.Print Item(1).SentOn

    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
       For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                'I = I + 1
            End If
       Next Atmt
   Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
   ' If I > 0 Then
       ' MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
   ' Else
       ' MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
   ' End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)

    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Folder
    Dim SubFolder As Folder

    Dim subFolderItems As Items

    Dim Atmt As attachment

    Dim FileName As String

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    Set subFolderItems = SubFolder.Items

    If subFolderItems.count > 0 Then

        subFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

        For Each Atmt In subFolderItems(1).Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            End If
        Next Atmt

    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set subFolderItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

Consider ItemAdd. The most recent item is already known. [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)

Comment: mark it as an answer so everyone knows its closed (and to give the responder credit)