# DASL query to restrict tp emails which have recipients outside our organization

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to restrict emails which have recipients outside our organization using my domain.

Is there a way to restrict emails using NOT LIKE condition?

I am using the Outlook Table approach as below

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & " urn:schemas:httpmail:ToEmailAddress" & " Not Like '%DomainName%'"  
OR "urn:schemas:httpmail:CCEmailAddress" & " Not Like '%DomainName%'"  
OR "urn:schemas:httpmail:SenderEmailAddress" & " Not Like '%DomainName%'"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268976/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender and recipients inside your Exchange domain are converted to GAL objects with the address type of `"EX"` (as opposed to `"SMTP"`) even if a message was originated from outside your org and was sent to an SMTP address - take a look at existing messages with [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

It is easy to create a query on the `SenderEmailType` property == "EX". For the recipients, however, OOM won't help you - it won't let you create subrestrictions on recipient properties (`PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS`); you would need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language - I am also its author) for that - it allows to specify `Recipients` / `To` / `CC` / `BCC` in `Find` / `Restrict` queries..