# Change Flagstatus on moving to Shared Mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

Is it possible to change the Flagstatus of emails moved to a folder in a shared mailbox?

Example: I receive a new mail and mark it with a red flag. Then, when the job is completed, I move the mail to the folder "Completed".

After moving the mail to this folder, I want the Flagstatus to be "olFlagComplete" (Green Flag) and every time I open Outlook, the code should check the folder for mails with red flag (e.g. Mails moved from mobile phone) and set it to green flag.

I tried the following, but nothing happened.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("name@company.com")
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Completed")
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Mail As MailItem

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("name@company.com")
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Completed")

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = Item

        If Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked Then
            'Set ItemCopy = Item.Copy ' Copy Flagged item
            'ItemCopy.Move olFolder ' Move Copied item
            Set Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
        End If

        Set Item = Nothing
        'Set ItemCopy = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is this what you are trying to do?*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim Item As Object
    Mark_Items Item
End Sub

Private Function Mark_Items(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com")

    Dim olShareInbox As Outlook.folder
    Set olShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)

    Dim Completed_Fldrs As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Completed_Fldrs = olShareInbox.Folders("Completed")

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & _
                           Chr(34) & ">1"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Completed_Fldrs.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Dim Mail As MailItem

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Mail = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Mail.Subject
            Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
            Mail.Save
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Shows an error on starting Outlook. Can't find the "Completed" Folder. By Debugging it Shows "Nothing" for the "Completed_Fldrs"

Comment: Not really, but I can usually customize the code to my needs. Now the code works. As I can see from forums, the problem was the access to subfolders of a shared mailbox. I have solved it with this line: "Set Completed_Fldrs = olNs.GetFolderFromID("xxx")". Can you explain me how the filter works, so what exactly is filtered?

Comment: @IrinaG. see links on the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268976/4539709

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help here is valuable :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The first task is to mark all completed items with a green flag at startup:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("name@company.com")
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Completed")
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
    For Each Item In Items
      If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = Item

        If Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked Then
            Set Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
        End If
      End If
     Next 

End Sub
```

2. The second part is to handle newly added items to the `Completed` folder:

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = Item

        If Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked Then            
            Set Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
        End If        
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When i put the Code to "ThisOutlookSession", then Close and open Outlook, nothing is happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the message afterwards - call `Mail.Save` after setting the `FlagStatus` property.