# Open Reply All window when specific email is received

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a script to open the Reply All window automatically when a specific email is received.

Also for it to include specific text in the body, I don't want the email to be send just want the window to open.

I have tried the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplyMSG()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply

For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
        olReply.HTMLBody = "TEXT " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
    olReply.Display

    'olReply.Send
Next olItem
End Sub
```

This will Open the email that is selected in the inbox rather than the email that was just received.

How can I change this to Reply All on the specific email?

Comment: Please post what you have tried. We are not a code delivery service, we are here to help solve technical problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Should be something like this*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olMsg As mailitem

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        Set olMsg = Item
        ReplyMSG olMsg
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub ReplyMSG(ByVal Item As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim olReply As mailitem ' Reply 

    If (InStr(1, Item.Body, "Text to Search", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        Set olReply = Item.ReplyAll

        olReply.HTMLBody = "TEXT " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display
        'olReply.Send
    End If

End Sub
```

> *Code goes under `ThisOutlookSession`*