# VBA MailItem.Add only triggering once?

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I have written a brief piece of code to perform certain actions when an e-mail arrives in the mailbox, but it only seems to work for the first e-mail that arrives immediately after the code is saved, after that nothing happens for subsequent e-mails.

I have put a watch on the code, and nothing is triggered, so it is not just a subsequent error in the subsequent code.

Code is (in the session object):

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private sub Application_Startup()
Dim objWatchFolder as Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.Getnamespace("MAPI")
Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item as Object)
    ' Do this, that, the other, passing the e-mail to other subroutines
    ' No problems in this code.
End Sub
```

Any guidance or pointers that can be given would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are defined `objItems`

Comment: Hi there, sorry I'm afraid I don't understand the question!

Comment: You are using objects without declaring them (or at least without showing how they are declared). Here the only declared object is `objWathchFolder`, but we don't have declarations for `objNS` nor `objItem`. Note that if they are not declared as global, they only have a locale declaration range (and are destroyed at the end of `Application_Startup`

Comment: Apologies, with you now:

    Private objNS as Outlook.NameSpace
    Private WithEvents objItems as Outlook.Items

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52812765/edit) your question to add the declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please restart your Outlook if you use the WithEvents. However, please try to the following code:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

  On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item 
    ' ******************
    ' do something here
    ' ******************
  End If
ProgramExit: 
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
  Resume ProgramExit 
End Sub
```

Reference link:[How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)