# Message box when I receive mail in outlook

Tags: outlook, autohotkey, sysinternals

I would like to make message pop-up in Autohotkey when there is new message in Outlook. I have tried to use `ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")` with no joy. Also documentation for COM objects is pretty vague on Autohotkey site. Message should be like `msgbox New Mail Received`. This is similar to default message pop-up in Outlook. I just need this in AHK.

Main reason is that I'm using [Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) from Sysinternals. This program makes 4 separated desktops. When I run outlook on one desktop, I can't see new message pop-up from outlook on the other desktop. I need a simple AHK script that will tell me when there is a new mail, when I'm on different desktop than the one that is running Outlook.

Comment: A little confused. As I know, A Desktop Alert is a notification that appears on your desktop outlook when you receive a new email message. So why you want to should be the another pop-up?

Comment: Because I need pop-up in AHK when mail is received.

Comment: In Outlook, create VBA macro triggered on arrival of the e-mail which will use command line to call your AHK code with appropriate command-line parameters. Each of these steps is a separate area which you might want to explore better.

Comment: @miroxlav. That is like last resort. If there is no way to do it in AHK alone.

Answer (score 0):

In the System-StatusBar, their is an icon of outlook, which changes\animates for sometime when a new mail is received.
We can use AutoHotKey > ImageSearch/PixelSearch for the same to find the difference.

- Add a SetTimer with ImageSearch/PixelSearch.
- Compare and If difference is found >> You Got A Mail.

As Simple As That.  If you need futher help with Scripting, Please feel free :)

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Outlook is running only on one desktop. There is no outlook icon on system tray.

Comment: It will be hidden in the menu >> in system-tray >> Show Hidden Icons, there you will find it (it will be an icon > pointing upwards)

Comment: Also check > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to AHK but after some research I came up with the following AHK script which should do what you need:

```
oOutlook = ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
ComObjConnect(oOutlook, "outlook_")
return

outlook_NewMail() ;uses the COM event NewMail
{
    msgbox New Mail Received
    oOutlook.Visible := 1  ;make Outlook visible
    oOutlook.Activate      ;and bring to front
}
```

To stop listening to the outlook COM events use

```
ComObjConnect(oOutlook)
```