# How to set reference to non-default folder (to send mail when new mail is added to the folder)?

Tags: vba, email, events, outlook, triggers

I would like to send a mail to different team mail addresses when a new mail is drag-and-dropped to their respective folder.

If someone drag and drop a mail into SubFolderTeam1, a mail will be sent to MailTeam1.

Same when we drag and drop a mail into SubFolderTeam2, a mail will be sent to MailTeam2.

**My folder structure:**

- Inbox
- Parent Folder:

  - SubFolderTeam1
  - SubFolderTeam2

**Team mail addresses:**

- MailTeam1
- MailTeam2

The Parent Folder containing the Sub Folders is at the same level as the Default Folder "Inbox".

I have tried something based on the answers of this question:
[How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item
    ' ******************
    
    'do the magic please
    
    ' ******************
  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Combined with the below.

```
Sub Send_Emails()

  Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

  Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With OutlookMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "Dear Team1" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please do you job. Thanks" & .HTMLBody
    .To = "MailTeam1@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Test Subject"
    .Send
  End With

End Sub
```

I tried to insert the second structure of code within the first one.
I tried to run them separately: first code on a Class Module, the second on a classic Module.
And several other things that have no real sense in our dimension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance for sending emails:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item
    ' ******************
    
    'do the magic please
    
    ' ******************
    Send_Emails
  
  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Sub Send_Emails()

  Set OutlookMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With OutlookMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "Dear Team1" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please do you job. Thanks" & .HTMLBody
    .To = "MailTeam1@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Test Subject"
    .Send
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your suggestions, however it does not take into account that i have to send a different mail to different team depending on where i drag and drop my mail (SubFolderTeam1  or SubFolderTeam2).

Answer (score 0):

You can start at a default folder then navigate to the applicable folders. You will need ItemAdd code for each folder.

Code goes in the ThisOutlookSession module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents Items1 As items
Private WithEvents Items2 As items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim inBox As folder
    Dim mailBox As folder
    
    Dim firstLevelFldr As folder
    Dim secondLevelFldr As folder
    
    Set inBox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Set mailBox = inBox.Parent
    'Debug.Print mailBox
    
    Set firstLevelFldr = mailBox.folders("Parent Folder")
    'Debug.Print firstLevelFldr
    
    Set secondLevelFldr = firstLevelFldr.folders("SubFolderTeam1")
    'Debug.Print secondLevelFldr
    Set Items1 = secondLevelFldr.items
    
    Set secondLevelFldr = firstLevelFldr.folders("SubFolderTeam2")
    'Debug.Print secondLevelFldr
    Set Items2 = secondLevelFldr.items
    
End Sub


Private Sub Items1_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    
    Dim OutlookMail As mailItem
    
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    
        Set OutlookMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
        With OutlookMail
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Display
            .HTMLBody = "Dear Team1" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please do you job. Thanks" & .HTMLBody
            .To = "MailTeam1@gmail.com"
            .Subject = "Test Subject"
            .Send
        End With
  
    End If
  
End Sub


Private Sub Items2_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    
    Dim OutlookMail As mailItem
    
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    
        Set OutlookMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With OutlookMail
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Display
            .HTMLBody = "Dear Team2" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please do you job. Thanks" & .HTMLBody
            .To = "MailTeam2@gmail.com"
            .Subject = "Test Subject"
            .Send
        End With
  
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niton, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It looks good to me, but when i tried to drag and drop a mail in the subfolders SubFolderTeam1 and SubFolderTeam2, no mail was sent .
I have entered the Application_Startup() part under a class module and Items1_ItemAdd/Items2_ItemAdd under a normal Modules.
I have also tried to do a simple copy/paste in the class module (obviously adapting my variables and text to my needs) but result was the same and no mail was sent.
Is there something i have done wrong ? the ItemAdd approach seems to be the solution but could not say where i failed.

Comment: The last line here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267757/1571407 indicates where the code goes.

Comment: It worked as expected. You are awesome Niton. thanks a lot for your help.