# Detect changes in folders of multiple account of outlook and send mail to specified address

Tags: vba, outlook

I manage several mail accounts in my `Outlook` and I want to check if there is any change happens in any of the mails folder (received a mail). Then check Folder name is "My Out Folder" then it should forward that mail to specified account i.e `"ABC@gmail.com"`

The following code only handle first Mail Account folders. I don't want to use several variables for every mail so I am looking for a way to create class module so that it can detect Change_events in all the emails. only trigger when the folder name is "My Out Folder".
Following is in class "ThisOutlookSession":

```
Const FowardEmailAddress As String = "ABC@gmail.com"
Public WithEvents myOutFolder As Outlook.Folders
Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set MyNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myOutFolder = MyNS.Folders(1).Folders
    
End Sub

Private Sub myOutFolder_FolderChange(ByVal Folder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim FowardItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
    If Folder.Name = "My Out Folder" Then
        
        Set FowardItem = Folder.Items.GetFirst
        
        AutoForwardAllSentItems FowardItem, FowardEmailAddress
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

code of AutoForwardAllSentItems() is in module:

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem, FM$)
    
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set myFwd = Item.Forward
    
    myFwd.Recipients.Add FM
    
    myFwd.Send
    'myFwd.Display
    Set myFwd = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I don't know what is best way to achieved the same results.

Comment: The ItemAdd event will trigger when an item enters a folder. You will need a listener on each folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497972/adding-listeners-to-different-folders-in-outlook and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837985/how-to-set-reference-to-non-default-folder-to-send-mail-when-new-mail-is-added

Comment: This demonstrates how to trigger an event on a collection of folders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881358/run-code-when-new-email-comes-to-any-subfolder-in-a-shared-mailbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to each folder separately. To iterate over all stores in Outlook you can use the [Namespace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. Use the `Stores` and `Store` objects to enumerate all folders and search folders on all stores in the current session. For example:

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores 
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If
End Sub
```

In your case it seems you just need to get the "My Out Folder" of each store and subscribe to the events. The [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method returns a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. So, you may get any standard folder and then navigate the required one.

Also you need to distinguish the [Items.ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection/folder and the [Items.ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) event which is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed.