# Auto download attachment from mail with particular subject in a shared Outlook mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

This is code to download attachments from mail with a certain subject from my Inbox.

I created a rule for the code to run.

How do I tweak the script to access a shared folder in the mailbox?

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are appending a backslash directly after an existing backslash?

Comment: Above code is working perfectly, which is downloading from inbox.  and my requirement is to download the attached file from shared outlook mailbox.

Comment: Have you tried removing one of the backslashes as @braX suggested? Perhaps like this `saveFolder = "N:\UAE\Dubai\Xfer\Libin\Log"`

Comment: Hi Dear, Can you understand my question?

Comment: @Libin The double backslash is non-fatal and appears frequently in this code. As you can see it has been a distraction that has caused you some frustration.

Comment: @Libin Do you pass itm into the code through a rule?

Comment: yes i have create rule for that code to run.

Comment: Given you want to run the code automatically there is the ItemAdd event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook You will have to add code for the subject condition and change the reference to point to the shared folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: attached file from shared outlook mailbox should download  to particular local folder in the disc drive not in outlook's folder. and downloading process is based on particular subject name. thank you for your response.