# Incoming message listener for items moved to a subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

Below is code that contains a couple solutions I tried.
The first being setting up a second items_by_add function and changing it from grabbing items from my second inbox "Data" to a subfolder of that inbox "adam.".
I then tried leveraging the beforeItemMove function.

With both of these attempts, the functions would not be called, but they would compile.

I can't change the rules of this inbox.

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set SubFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Set Inbox = objNS.Folders("my email").Folders("People").Folders("adam")
    Set Items = objNS.Folders.Item("Data").Folders.Item("Inbox").Items
    'Set Items1 = objNS.Folders.Item("my email").Folders.Item("Inbox").Item.BeforeItemMove(Outlook.MailItem, "adam", False)
    Set Items1 = objNS.Folders.BeforeItemM("my email").Folders.item("people").Folders.item("adam")
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        'save attachment
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub Items1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        'save attachment
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub SubFolder_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MoveTo = Inbox Then
        MsgBox Item.Subject & " was moved to Inbox"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook VBA create event listener for new emails and have it automatically download attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873437/outlook-vba-create-event-listener-for-new-emails-and-have-it-automatically-downl)

Comment: Are you missing a Global for `Items1` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Comment: Take an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox and tack on `.Folders("adam")`

Comment: @TimWilliams what do you mean by global?

Comment: I'm sorry @niton where do you think I should put the .folders("adam")?

Comment: @Tragamor haha no that was my previous thread

Comment: Edit the question. Add a drawing as in the link, or a picture of the folder structure.

Comment: You have `Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items` at the top of your module (so it's a Global variable) but you have no corresponding line for `Items1`, so no events will be registered for that item once  `Application_Startup` is done. Are you using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Navigate through all folders one at a time starting at the top and ending at adam.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition for the `Items1` object in the code. Ideally, the code should look like that:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Items1 As Outlook.Items
```

But I'd suggest handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.